# A function on set involved in product of measurable sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mathfrak{S}_1$ and $\mathfrak{S}_2$ be two families of measurable sets, and let $C\in\mathfrak{S}_1\times\mathfrak{S}_2$ be the countable union of disjoint sets, i.e. $C=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty C_n$ where $C_n=A_n\times B_n$, $A_n\in\mathfrak{S}_1$ and $B_n\in\mathfrak{S}_2$, and $\forall i\ne j$ $C_i\cap C_j=\emptyset$. Since $C\in\mathfrak{S}_1\times\mathfrak{S}_2$, it can be represented as the product of sets of each $\mathfrak{S}_i$: $C=A\times B$ where $A\in\mathfrak{S}_1$, $B\in\mathfrak{S}_2$.

Let $\mu_2$ be the $\sigma$-additive measure defined on $\mathfrak{S}_2$ and let $f_n:\bigcup_{S\in\mathfrak{S}_1}S\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ be the function defined by$$f_n(x)= \begin{cases} \mu_2(B_n) & \mbox{if } x\in A_n \\ 0 & \mbox{if } x\notin A_n \end{cases}$$I read in Kolmogorov and Fomin's *Elements of the Theory of Functions and Functional Analysis* (Graylock 1963, vol. 2, p. 67) that *it is easy to see* that $$\forall x\in A\quad\sum_n f_n(x)=\mu_2(B)$$I have tried to prove it by majorating and minorating the sum, but I have not been able to prove this interesting lemma. Could anybody be so kind to explain why this equality holds? I $\infty$-ly thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to visualize this fact is to think of $C = A \times B$ as a rectangle (Cartesian product of intervals) and $\{C_n\}_n$ is a family of disjoint rectangles covering $C$.

Let $x \in A$. Consider the set $I = \{n \in \mathbb{N} | x \in A_n\}$. We claim that $B_n \cap B_m = \emptyset$ whenever $n,m \in I$ with $n \neq m$ and that
$$B = \bigcup_{n \in I}B_n.$$

To see the first fact, take $n,m \in I$, $n \neq m$. If $y \in B_n \cap B_m$, then $(x,y) \in C_n \cap C_m$, which is a contradiction: therefore, $B_n \cap B_m = \emptyset$.

For the second fact, take $y \in B$. Since $(x,y) \in C$, it follows that $(x,y) \in C_n = A_n \times B_n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Since $x \in A_n$, it follows that $n \in I$. Therefore, $y \in B_n$, and thus we have shown that $\bigcup_{n \in I}B_n = B$. Hence, since $\mu_2$ is $\sigma$-additive, 
$$\sum_{n} f_n(x) = \sum_{n \in I} \mu_2(B_n) = \mu_2(B).$$

Comment: Wow: it's fascinating. Agradeço você de todo coração!